# FileNotFoundErrorで.pyファイルの先に.tsvファイルが存在する

Tags: python, python3, anaconda, anaconda3

以下のサンプルコードは、
https://github.com/daitan-innovation/cnn-audio-denoiser
こちらのものになります

```
from mozilla_common_voice import MozillaCommonVoiceDataset
from urban_sound_8K import UrbanSound8K
from dataset import Dataset
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore')

mozilla_basepath = r'C:\Users\ユーザ名\cnn-audio-denoiser-master\data_processing\mozilla_common_voice'
urbansound_basepath = r'C:\Users\ユーザ名\cnn-audio-denoiser-master\data_processing\UrbanSound8K'

mcv = MozillaCommonVoiceDataset(mozilla_basepath, val_dataset_size=1000)
clean_train_filenames, clean_val_filenames = mcv.get_train_val_filenames()　　→def get_train_val_filenames(self):に移動
```

上記のコードの
mcv = MozillaCommonVoiceDataset(mozilla_basepath, val_dataset_size=1000)
でmozilla_common_voiceファイルに移動して、

```
np.random.seed(999)

class MozillaCommonVoiceDataset:

    def __init__(self, basepath, *, val_dataset_size):
        self.basepath = basepath
        self.val_dataset_size = val_dataset_size

    def _get_common_voice_filenames(self, dataframe_name='train.tsv'):
        mozilla_metadata = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(self.basepath, dataframe_name), sep='\t')
        clean_files = mozilla_metadata['path'].values
        np.random.shuffle(clean_files)
        print("Total number of training examples:", len(clean_files))
        return clean_files

    def get_train_val_filenames(self):
        clean_files = self._get_common_voice_filenames(dataframe_name='train.tsv')
→def _get_common_voice_filenames(self, dataframe_name='train.tsv'):に移動
```

こちらの21行目と14行目に移動してプログラムが進んでいたのですが、

該当エラーコード

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-70173126a5a3> in <module>
     11 
     12 mcv = MozillaCommonVoiceDataset(mozilla_basepath, val_dataset_size=1000)
---> 13 clean_train_filenames, clean_val_filenames = mcv.get_train_val_filenames()
     14 
     15 us8K = UrbanSound8K(urbansound_basepath, val_dataset_size=200)

~\mozilla_common_voice.py in get_train_val_filenames(self)
     19 
     20     def get_train_val_filenames(self):
---> 21         clean_files = self._get_common_voice_filenames(dataframe_name='train.tsv')
     22 
     23         # resolve full path

~\mozilla_common_voice.py in _get_common_voice_filenames(self, dataframe_name)
     12 
     13     def _get_common_voice_filenames(self, dataframe_name='train.tsv'):
---> 14         mozilla_metadata = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(self.basepath, dataframe_name), sep='\t')
     15         clean_files = mozilla_metadata['path'].values
     16         np.random.shuffle(clean_files)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    684     )
    685 
--> 686     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    687 
    688 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    450 
    451     # Create the parser.
--> 452     parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
    453 
    454     if chunksize or iterator:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    934             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    935 
--> 936         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    937 
    938     def close(self):

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1166     def _make_engine(self, engine="c"):
   1167         if engine == "c":
-> 1168             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1169         else:
   1170             if engine == "python":

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1996         kwds["usecols"] = self.usecols
   1997 
-> 1998         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1999         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
   2000 

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\ユーザ名\\cnn-audio-denoiser-master\\data_processing\\mozilla_common_voice\\train.tsv'
```

上記のエラーコードが出てきました。
mozilla_common_voiceファイルは、.pyファイルであり、それ以降にtrain.tsvファイルが存在していることが理解できません。フォルダ内に格納されているのでしたらわかるのですが、エラーを見る通り、.pyファイルの中に.tsvファイルが存在しているのです。

こちらの謎とこのFileNotFoundErrorの解決方法を教えていただきたいです。

プログラムが長く必要不十分にソースコードを記入してある可能性がありますので、できる限りでコメントで追記します。

Comment: 自分自身で[daitan-innovation/cnn-audio-denoiser/create_dataset.py#L8](https://github.com/daitan-innovation/cnn-audio-denoiser/blob/master/create_dataset.py#L8)やその下の行を書き変えていますよね。その結果のとおりに動作していると思われます。そこに何(`train.tsv`(その下の行は`UrbanSound8K.csv`)を格納あるいはそれが存在するフォルダのパス名)を指定すべきか理解した上で変更した方が良いでしょう。

Comment: 今回の問題の行の始まりがmozilla_basepathで、パスを参照しているという意味では、私が書き換えた内容ともとプログラムは同じように思えます。もし、ソースコードと私の書き替えたコードの意味が全く違うものであるのなら報告してくれると助かります。また、私は、mozilla_common_voiceのプログラムは一切書き加えておりません。

Comment: 元のパスが`/home/thallessilva/Documents/datasets/en`であり、貴方が`C:\Users\ユーザ名\cnn-audio-denoiser-master\data_processing\mozilla_common_voice`と言う風に`.py`と同じファイル名部分のフォルダ名を指定していて、そのフォルダやそこに`train.tsv`ファイルが存在しないためにエラーになったのを気付かずにエラーの原因を`.py`ファイル(の先に`.tsv`が指定されているように見える)だと思い違いしているからですね。例えばパスの指定を`C:\Users\ユーザ名\cnn-audio-denoiser-master\datasets\en`とでもして`.py`ファイル名との関係を無くしてみれば、現在のエラーメッセージのとおり、指定のフォルダやファイルが存在しないからだとわかるでしょう。

Comment: 私はmozilla_common_voiceのファイルが.pyのものだと思い込んでいました。よく見てみると、path指定の時点で.pyと入力してはいなかったので私の勘違いでした。enというフォルダを作り、その中にtrain.tsvのファイルを入れた所、今回のエラーはなくなりました。（urbansound8kのpathも同じ方法で解決できた。）

Comment: この質問のエラーは解決しました。（以降のコードでUnicorderrorが出てしまったのでこちらはまた新しく質問を作ります。）ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

`README.md` には以下の様な文言があります。

> Dataset
>
> Part of the dataset used to train the original system is now available to download
>
> The zip file **contains 1 training file** (that is 10% of the data used to train the system), a validation file, and two audio files (not included in the training files) used to evaluate the model.

問題の `train.csv` はこの `ZIP` ファイルに入っているのでしょう。ただ、現時点では存在しませんが(いわゆるリンク切れ)。

Comment: Readmeのファイルはその通り開けませんでした。ですので Mozilla Common VoiceとUrbanSound8Kのサイトに移動して、そちらでダウンロードしました。(tar.gzファイル)こちらを解凍したら、中にtrain.tsvがあったのでそちらで実行してみようと思います。ありがとうございます。